# How to pass arguments (not command line arguments) to functions within batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I'm writing a batch file for automating the creation of typical folder structures for products that we sell. I would like to be able to call my batch file with 2 optional arguments; the name of the supplier and a file for creating lots of folders at once. If no supplier is supplied the script asks via standard input who the supplier is. If no file is supplied the script asks for the name of the folder you wish to create. If a file *is* passed as an argument I would like the script to read the file line by line and create a folder for each line, named after the contents of that line. Here is the `:readFile` function:

```
:readFile
    echo "Reading from file: %theFile%"
    FOR /F "delims=," %%a IN (%theFile%) do (
        call:makeFolder %%a
    )
    goto:EOF
```

Here is the `:makeFolder` function that optionally takes the argument of the name of the folder to create. If no argument is supplied it asks for the name via standard input.

```
:makeFolder  
    if [%1]==[] (
        set /p product="Enter product name: "
    ) else (
        set product=%1
    )
    if exist "P:\%supplier%\Products\%product%" (
        echo.
        echo The folder '%product%' already exists.
        echo.
        goto:EOF
    )
    mkdir "P:\%supplier%\Products\%product%\Images\Web Ready"
    mkdir "P:\%supplier%\Products\%product%\Images\Supplied"
    mkdir "P:\%supplier%\Products\%product%\Images\Edited"
    goto:EOF
```

My problem is that in the `:makeFolder` function `%1` refers to the 1st argument given on the command line, not the one provided in the `:readFile` function. How can I achieve this? Caveat: I'm *very* new to batch scripting so you may have to speak to me like I'm a bit stupid.

Comment: %1 is the first argument, if you got the first parameter from the command line, it could be possible that an 'exit /b'day is missing after your main code

Comment: @jeb: This should be an answer, in my opinion. I realise that it is a guess, but it is a likely guess. And even if it turns out wrong in the OP's case, it should still be there as a *possible* answer, for other people (those who might come across this question) to consider it.

Comment: @jeb I'm sorry I don't understand, what is `exit /b'day`? I understand that $1 is the first parameter from the command line, but as I understand it you also use $1 when referencing the first argument of a function. My question is what can I do to access the first argument passed to `:makeFolder` without referencing the 1st command line argument?

Comment: `%1` is the first parameter on the commandline only in the main part of the batch file. Inside a function, `%1` means the first parameter of that function. Inside a function you have no direct access to the parameters of the commandline.

Comment: I think you are wrong with your problem description. I suggest you to insert an `echo Parameter for makeFolder: %%a` before the call to it, and an `echo Parameter received %1` in the first line of makeFolder. This may help you to see what is happening.

Comment: @MrMisterMan :-) The `exit /b`day is only an artefact of my phone, it should read as `exit /b`

Comment: @jeb Aha! I was thinking it must be a typo. By the way you are all right. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I rebuild the file and it worked

```
@echo off
set "supplier=C:\temp\supp\"
set "product=Car"
echo test1,myComment,myValue > myFile.txt
call :readFile "myFile.txt"
EXIT /B

:readFile
echo "Reading from file: %~1"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=," %%a IN ("%~1") do (
    call :makeFolder %%a
)
goto:EOF

:makeFolder  
if "%1"=="" (
    set /p product="Enter product name: "
) else (
    set "product=%1"
)
if exist "%supplier%\Products\%product%" (
    echo(
    echo The folder '%product%' already exists.
    echo(
    goto:EOF
)
echo "%1"
echo mkdir "%supplier%\Products\%product%\Images\Web Ready"
echo mkdir "%supplier%\Products\%product%\Images\Supplied"
echo mkdir "%supplier%\Products\%product%\Images\Edited"
goto:EOF
```

But I would recommend to use delayed expansion, as you can got problems with the percent expansion of special characters( In this case not very relevant, as special characters are a bad choice for file/directory names).

Comment: ... expansion of (what?)

Comment: @Birger Good question, after 5 years I can't remember what I wanted to write, so I have to guess