# Getting function parameters gets command line parameters - batch

Tags: batch-file

I am passing command line arguments to a batch script and setting that to a variable like so:

```
SET dirWhereKept=%1
```

My problem is, I call a function inside the batch script with 3 arguments. When trying to get those 3 arguments, it gets the ones passed in via the command line instead:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /B') DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~i\" (
        rem nothing
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :checkIfWantedFile %%i "%%~xi" %%~zi
    )
)

:checkIfWantedFile
SET file=%~1
SET fileExtension=%~2
SET fileSizeInBytes=%~3

ECHO FILE: %file%
ECHO EXTENSION: %fileExtension%
ECHO SIZE: %fileSizeInBytes%
```

For example, if I pass in `"Avatar ECE (2009)"` as the command line argument (which is a directory) and then when calling the function I pass:

- `%%i`**:** `Avatar.mp4`
- `"%%~xi"`**:** `".mp4"`
- `%%~zi`: *some_int*

When I do the `ECHO`'s in `checkIfWantedFile`, the output will be:

```
FILE: Avatar ECE (2009)
EXTENSION:
SIZE:
```

As it's getting the command line arguments and not the function ones.

I've had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877495/how-to-pass-arguments-not-command-line-arguments-to-functions-within-batch-scr#7886915) and some others but cannot get it to work.

**EDIT:**

The intent of this batch script is to go into a given directory (*supplied by the command line arguments*) and extract and video file (`.mp4`, `.mkv`, `.avi`) that maybe be in there. Sometimes, the video files are nested in a sub-directory which is why I am checking if the item in the `FOR` loop is a folder or not. If it is, then the batch script was intended to go into the sub-directory and check whether there are any wanted video files in there or not and extract them.

I added the option that if the script comes across an unwanted file, it is deleted. This is not a requirement though.

The intent is also is that when the directory (*supplied in the command line arguments*) is cleared of all video files recursively, it is deleted.

Due to unwanted video sample files sometimes being present, I have put in a check as well to check the size of the file in MB, if it is `GTR` then the `%minimumSize%` then it is a wanted file and can be extracted

My full code is below:

```
@ECHO off

SET "dirWhereKept=%1"
SET mp4=".mp4"
SET mkv=".mkv"
SET avi=".avi"
SET needCompressingDir="E:\Need_compressing"
SET minimumSize=200

CD %needCompressingDir%
CD %dirWhereKept%
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /B') DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~i\" (
        rem do nothing
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO :EOF
        CALL :checkIfWantedFile "%%i" "%%~xi" "%%~zi"
    )
)

:checkIfWantedFile
SET file=%~1
SET fileExtension=%~2
SET fileSizeInBytes=%~3

IF "%fileExtension%" == %mp4% (
    CALL :checkFileSize %fileSizeInBytes%
) ELSE (
    IF "%fileExtension%" == %mkv% (
        CALL :checkFileSize %fileSizeInBytes%
    ) ELSE (
        IF "%fileExtension%" == %avi% (
            CALL :checkFileSize %fileSizeInBytes%
        ) ELSE (
            rem this is not required!
            CALL :deleteFile
        )
    )
)

:checkFileSize
SET /a fileSizeInMB=%~1/1024/1024

IF %fileSizeInMB% GTR %minimumSize% (
    CALL :moveFileToCompress
)

:deleteFile
ECHO "Delete called!"

:moveFileToCompress
MOVE %file% %needCompressingDir%
```

Comment: Always use quotes properly: change `SET dirWhereKept=%1` to `SET "dirWhereKept=%~1"`, so the quotes do not become part of the variable value, but prevent the line from failing upon special characters; then change `%%i` to `"%%~i"`, etc.; the `~` removes potential quotes; together with the explicit `""`, this ensures that there is always one pair of `""` around the values...

Answer (score 0):

Change **%%i** in the CALL statement to **"%%i"**

example:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "dirWhereKept=%~1"
IF /I NOT "%CD%"=="%~1" PUSHD "%~1"2>Nul||Exit/B
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO CALL :checkIfWantedFile "%%i" "%%~xi" "%%~zi"
TIMEOUT -1
EXIT/B

:checkIfWantedFile
ECHO FILE: %~1
ECHO EXTENSION: %~2
ECHO SIZE: %~3
```

Comment: Still get the same result

Comment: You cannot possibly get the same result! on your example you are passing five parameters "%~1=Avatar, %~2=ECE, %~3=(2009), %~4=.mp4, %~5=some_int", mine is passing "%~1=Avatar ECE (2009), %~2=.mp4, %~3=some_int"

Comment: I have figured out an error. On checking whether the current item is a folder or not,  if the item is **not** a folder then it does not go into the `else` condition so the function is never called. But if the function is never called, why is it invoked?

Comment: take a look at the example I have provided, it doesn't see 'folders' so there is no need for the condition. Your function is called because there is nothing to tell your code to stop before the checkIfWantedFile label

Comment: I need the check though to see if the item is a folder. If it is, I need to check whether files within it are of interest. So, basically, recursively going through sub-directories

Comment: I have updated the example again now that I have noted your input parameter. I have not performed a recursive check however, merely a check within the directory level provided. You could however do that with `FOR /R %%i IN (*.*)…`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simply that batch has no concept of a `section` or `procedure`. It simply executes the next statement until it reaches end-of-file or `exit`.

Consequently, the `call` executes the routine `:checkIfWantedFile` and when it reaches end-of-file, it returns to the next logical statement after the `call` - which is the routine `:checkIfWantedFile`, so it continues executing, using the parameters supplied to the batch itself as `%n`.

You need to insert a `goto :eof` line before the `:checkIfWantedFile` label so that the routine is skipped after it has been executed by the `call`. Note that the colon in `:eof` is critical. `:eof` is defined as end-of-file by `cmd`.

---

You are `call`ing a number of subroutines. You need to specifically `goto :eof` at the end of *each and every* subroutine, otherwise batch simply continues executing line-by-line. For instance

```
:deleteFile
ECHO "Delete called!"

:moveFileToCompress
MOVE %file% %needCompressingDir%
```

If you `call :deletefile` then the echo is executed, and the `move` is attempted.

If you `call :moveFileToCompress` then just the `move` is attempted.

If you change this to

```
:deleteFile
ECHO "Delete called!"

GOTO :EOF

:moveFileToCompress
MOVE %file% %needCompressingDir%

goto :eof
```

then
If you `call :deletefile` then the echo is executed.

If you `call :moveFileToCompress` then the `move` is attempted.

Certainly, a `goto :eof` at the end-of-file is redundant. I habitually use it so I don't need to remember to insert it before a new added-routine to prevent flow-through.

You would need to follow a similar pattern for each of the subroutines you `call`.

When I say "report" what I mean is that the batch `echo`es something to the console, so in your code

```
:checkIfWantedFile
SET file=%~1
SET fileExtension=%~2
SET fileSizeInBytes=%~3

ECHO FILE: %file%
ECHO EXTENSION: %fileExtension%
ECHO SIZE: %fileSizeInBytes%
```

This would set the variables and then **report** their values.

(btw - you may like to use

```
set file
```

for reporting these values, which will show the value and name of each existing variable that starts `file` - a lot less typing...)

Comment: Putting the `GOTO :EOF` completely terminates the batch script. Is there anyway to instead make it go to the next item in the `FOR` loop?

Comment: It will run through all of the items (filenames and directorynames) in the directory, do nothing if the name found exists as `.\namefound` and report after setting the variables, then continue to the next. When it has reached the end, it will terminate (if the `goto :eof`) is in place with the variables set to the last matching reported name. Perhaps if you were to explain clearly what your intention is, we could suggest an appropriate method. As it is, all we have is your code - we can analyse *that*, but we need a crystal ball to scry your reason for executing the code.

Comment: Thank you! I am confused on what you mean by setting the variables and reporting back though? I will edit my question so you can get a clear understanding of what I am trying to do.